# Solving Matrix Equations involving singular matrices in higher dimesnsions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a singular matrix. If $AXA=A,\ XAX=X$ and $AX=XA$, then what are the conditions on $A$ so that we obtain a solution?

Specifically, can we say that $A$ is 
not nilpotent or a projection? What if we restrict $n$ to $2$. I easily obtained that $AX$ is idempotent. But, I am unable to proceed further. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If $AXA=A,\ XAX=X\ $ and $AX=XA$, then $X$ is called the group inverse of $A$.

A singular matrix $A\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ has a group inverse $ \iff rank(A)=rank(A^2)$.

In this case, the group inverse of $A$ is unique.

Comment: sorry, could you please elaborate?